# Using Excel 2007, how to autofill cells from one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I want to put the Employee's Number in this sheet.

[image]

...so the Employee's information can show based on this sheet.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

On cell 'B9' put `=VLOOKUP($B$4,Sheet2!$A$2:$P$24,2,FALSE)`

On cell 'B10' put `=VLOOKUP($B$4,Sheet2!$A$2:$P$24,3,FALSE)`

VLOOKUP will search the value *($B$4)* on a range *(Sheet2!$A$2:$P$24)* and bring the value on a column *(2 for name, 3 for position)* if there is a perfect match *(FALSE)*.

Comment: Why? In the formula I supposed that the sheetname was *Sheet2*. Could it be the problem?